# make specific cluster

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have set of coordinates. I want to make clusters in which every point is within 1.5 distance unit of it's neighbor.

ex of point coordinates:

```
{{-12.945, 20.6509, 12.5901}, {-13.4452, 20.307, 111.626}, 
{-12.9731, 22.8458, 12.4215}, {-13.2381, 24.8167, 10.7147}, 
{-11.3668, 23.3908,11.8499}, {-11.6828, 23.7311, 10.8839}, 
{-13.3929, 21.1835, 9.86324}, {-11.5016, 21.3324, 10.1392}, 
{-12.3079, 22.096, 8.57246}, {-12.5268, 20.9679, 10.5444}, 
{-12.1951, 24.5423, 10.1807}, {-11.8887, 22.3883, 10.0751}, 
{-14.2529, 20.4808, 9.81084}, {-11.9876, 21.8094, 11.0478}, 
{-12.3718, 23.6176, 11.8266}, {-11.6179, 20.8324, 11.2154}, 
{-12.5927, 21.7492, 12.5087}, {-12.1665, 24.6649, 11.2909}, 
{-12.3854, 21.5571, 9.51876}, {-12.2237, 23.4278, 9.9787}}
```

what is the quickest way in `Mathematica` for this (for large data sets).

I tried this to find all points that are within mentioned distance:

```
Table[Select[List, EuclideanDistance[List[[i]], #] < 1.5 &], {i, 1, Length[[List]]}]
```

but now I have troubles to join all sets that have common elements.

Comment: I formatted your code. As you have been here a while, you should learn how to do so, yourself. To see what changes I made, click on the "Edited ..." link above my gravitar.

Comment: @rcollyer: my apologize. I'll be more careful.

Comment: how'd you cluster, if you have say points `{0,0,0}`, `{0,0,1}` and `{0,0,2}`? I.e. the 2nd point could be clustered with both other, but the 1st not with the 3rd

Comment: 'two clusters' means there is no point in one being within 1.5 distance unit of any point from another cluster. so these three numbers are all in one cluster together.

Comment: No! 
in each cluster, for any points, there is at least one point to be within it's 1.5.
like: {0,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,0,2} are in one cluster but 1st and 3rd are 2 units apart.

Comment: Something like `Gather[data, EuclideanDistance[#1, #2] < 1.5 &]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible alteernative, I was working on while Kuba posted his answer :-)
I also started by using FixedPoint and the inner loop seems to work but the outer one is easier with While.

```
c = {{-12.945, 20.6509, 12.5901}, {-13.4452, 20.307, 
    111.626}, {-12.9731, 22.8458, 12.4215}, {-13.2381, 24.8167, 
    10.7147}, {-11.3668, 23.3908, 11.8499}, {-11.6828, 23.7311, 
    10.8839}, {-13.3929, 21.1835, 9.86324}, {-11.5016, 21.3324, 
    10.1392}, {-12.3079, 22.096, 8.57246}, {-12.5268, 20.9679, 
    10.5444}, {-12.1951, 24.5423, 10.1807}, {-11.8887, 22.3883, 
    10.0751}, {-14.2529, 20.4808, 9.81084}, {-11.9876, 21.8094, 
    11.0478}, {-12.3718, 23.6176, 11.8266}, {-11.6179, 20.8324, 
    11.2154}, {-12.5927, 21.7492, 12.5087}, {-12.1665, 24.6649, 
    11.2909}, {-12.3854, 21.5571, 9.51876}, {-12.2237, 23.4278, 
    9.9787}};
MyClustering[data_List, distance_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[{dataoriginal = data, res = {}, temp = {}},
  While[dataoriginal =!= {},
   temp = {};
   AppendTo[res,
    FixedPoint[(
       Map[
        Function[p, 
         temp = Join[temp, 
           Select[dataoriginal, EuclideanDistance[#, p] < distance &]];
         dataoriginal = Complement[dataoriginal, temp]], #]; 
       temp) &, {dataoriginal[[1]]}]]];
  Return[res]]
```

Just few notes: dataoriginal is needed because I modify the original list and the argument of a function (data in that case) cannot be modified inside the function's body. 
For huge lists AppendTo is generally slow, so a possible alternative is

res = Join[{res}, FixedPoint[...]]

Comment: It seems approach is the same :) but yours is tidy and compact +1. I will probably delete mine then, but later, I don't have time now to parse this. :)

Comment: @Kuba: I was focused on a annoying job so when I saw this question I shifted my attention on Mathematica and spent a couple of hours just to have an alibi for the other job not completed ;-)

Comment: haha, the same here, but now I have to focus back on work :P

Answer (score 4):

Here's a different approach, though I think it's quite inefficient.

I treat the points as vertices in a graph. I check each pair of points and if the distance between them is less than 1.5 I connect them with an edge. The clusters are just the `ConnectedComponents` of the graph.

```
v = Range @ Length @ data;
e = UndirectedEdge @@@ Select[Subsets[v, {2}], EuclideanDistance @@ data[[#]] < 1.5 &];

ConnectedComponents @ Graph[v, e]
(* {{14, 8, 10, 12, 16, 19, 7, 20, 9, 13, 6, 11, 5, 15, 18, 4, 3, 17, 1}, {2}} *)
```

Comment: `SparseArray\`StronglyConnectedComponents@SparseArray@UnitStep[1.5^2 - DistanceMatrix@data]` follows the same logic but uses an undocumented internal function first publicized by [Carl Woll](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2005/Nov/msg00060.html). He found it to be quite fast.

Comment: @RayKoopman I highly encourage you to pose an answer with this method. Also, other mentioned in this link are wort recalling.

Answer (score 2):

This is my interpretation:

your cluster is a set of points that for each one there is at least one within 1.5 distance.

I will not be surprised if there is some kind of one-liner but I haven't played with `Clusters` etc much.

This is straightforward approach:

```
data = (* your data*)

SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[cluster_] := Module[{n = Length@cluster},
               Do[
                cluster = Join[cluster, 
                               Select[data, EuclideanDistance[#, cluster[[i]]] < 1.5 &]
                              ];
                           data = Complement[data, cluster];
                 , {i, n}];
               cluster
               ];
```

The the inner loop should be done with `FixedPoint` but I've failed in implementation so I used `While`:

```
i = 0;
While[Length[data] > 0,
      i++;
      clusters[i] = data[[{1}]];
      data = Rest@data;
      start = 0;
      end = 1;
      While[start != end,
            With[{i = i}, start = Length@clusters[i]; 
                          f[clusters[i]]; 
                          end = Length@clusters[i]];
           ];
     ]

set = clusters /@ Range@i

ListPointPlot3D[set, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize@10, 
                     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Looks reasonable :)

I have to focus and it will take some time to write explanation, be patient. Or maybe it will be pointless if this is an overkill :)