# Gather dependency on list order?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I get intrigued about `Gather` behavior [on this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32741/2266).
I thought that `Gather` was invariant under list order?

Here is the result I spect:

```
l1={{1, 1}, {0, 0}, {2, 2}, {5, 5}, {4, 4}, {6, 6}}
Gather[l1,ManhattanDistance[#1, #2] <= 2 &]
```

> {{{1,1},{0,0},{2,2}},{{5,5},{4,4},{6,6}}}

When the list order is changed, I get this:

```
l2={{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}}
Gather[l2,ManhattanDistance[#1,#2]<= 2&]
```

> {{{0,0},{1,1}},{{2,2}},{{4,4},{5,5}},{{6,6}}}

Someone know why?

Comment: Documentation is obscure about this.

Comment: Counter question: how can it determine the correct order? E.g. `{4,5}>{5,4}` or `{4,5}<{5,4}`?

Comment: Well.. I got the point. I don't know if I should delete this question.

Comment: I don;t know where's @ssch 's comment but I think he's right. Relation has to be transitive. If it's not the result may vary with order. For example, for the case of `l2` the result `{{{0,0}}, {{1,1}, {2,2}}, {{4,4}}, {{5,5}, {6,6}}}` is as good as the one you obtained.

Comment: The test function goes from the first to the last list element, from left to right. It collects what happens in the first pass, what is iqual is collected. Then start again in the second argument, excluded was was collected in the past.

Comment: @Murta No, it starts again as soon as it meets `False`. Try `Reap@Gather[l2, (Sow[{#, #2}]; ManhattanDistance[#1, #2] <= 2) &]`

Comment: @Kuba nice tip to prospect function operation! +1

Comment: @Murta I thought you wanted a similar result to the first example. I took the test here and it was different. That's right? About: `Reap@Gather[l2, (Sow[{#, #2}]; ManhattanDistance[#1, #2] <= 2) &]`