# Fast way to extract data from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I used `data=Table[{i,f[i]},{i,1,n}]` to produce a list, here `n` is greater than 2^20 = 1048576.
The function f(N) runs in time `O(N*Log(N))`, it is defined as:

```
Mod[PowerMod[i,n,n]-i,n] (n is an argument in a function which use this)
```

Now I want to give a table which shows the values of i that f(i) is 0, and another table for f(i) non-zero.

I used `zero = Select[data,#[[2]]==0&]`, but it is slow in the following sense:

```
n=2^22, timing for data =  10.171, timing for zero =  4.508
n=2^23, timing for data =  21.606, timing for zero =  9.250
n=2^24, timing for data =  43.399, timing for zero = 17.971
n=2^25, timing for data =  84.209, timing for zero = 34.523
n=2^26, timing for data = 167.420, timing for zero = 71.885
```

The hardest computation is the `data`, But after that I want to have a much faster way to know the zeros of the function `f`.

Of course I can use `For` or `Do` to append the zeros `i` each time f(i) is zero. But we know that `AppendTo` is slow, and `For` or `Do` is slower than `Table`.

Is there any way to construct a list + exact data fast?

---

Update:

Thanks for all the suggestion. Here is a table of comparison.
The green columns is to find i such that `f[i]=0` and the white columns (excluding the 1st and 2nd column) is to find i such that `f[i]!=0`. The last 2 columns are in fact using "NonzeroPositions" (the last column) as mentioned by ubpdqn, then do the complement (the second last column). This method is faster.

[image]

Comment: Can you please give `f[i]`? And how can you take `#[[3]]` while `Length@data[[1]]` is `2`?

Comment: @Öskå:Sorry, it is a typo. In my actual code, it should be 3, but I simplify the code here, so it should be 2. Thanks.

Comment: @user565739  thank you for the update and performance assessment. rasher answer more thoughtful and analytical than mine. Just wanted to post an alternative exploiting "NonzeroPositions".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Positions of zeros and non-zeros:

```
dataZeros = SparseArray[1 - Unitize[data[[All, 2]]]]["AdjacencyLists"]; // Timing

dataNonZeros = SparseArray[Unitize[data[[All, 2]]]]["AdjacencyLists"]; // Timing

(* 
{0.249602,Null}
{0.374402,Null}
*)
```

That's for a 1M entry table, on a *netbook*. Just use the result with `Part` or `Extract` to get the actual data. The first for zero positions can also be done (with slightly faster results via verbosity) as:

```
dataZeros = SparseArray[Unitize[data[[All, 2]]], Automatic, 1]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

You can also use

```
Pick[data, Unitize[data[[All, 2]]], 0]
Pick[data, Unitize[data[[All, 2]]], 1]
```

to do the same, and get datasets directly.

For ideas on how the (sparsely documented) feature of `SparseArray` and things like `Unitize` have potentially huge performance benefits, search for the terms on the site, have a look an *Mr. Wizard*'s posts regarding them, and see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42352/finding-connected-components-in-an-array/42619#42619) where using it made a problem solvable thousands of times more quickly.

As far as *creating* it more quickly, short of going parallel with multiple kernels, doing it as

```
Array[{#,f[#]}&,n]
```

*might* save 10% or so in time.

Edit: I've found this quite a bit faster for creation:

```
n = 1000000

data = Table[{i, Mod[PowerMod[i, n, n] - i, n]}, {i, 1, n}]; // Timing

data2 = Transpose[{l = Range[n], Mod[PowerMod[l, n, n] - l, n]}]; // Timing

data == data2

(*
{18.064916,Null}
{8.205653,Null}
True
*)
```

Timings again on lounge-netbook, curious what your results are...

Comment: `Compile` can also speed up the creation a lot...but be careful with large integer handling!

Comment: @PlatoManiac: good point - I forget about compile since I mostly deal symbolically or arbitrary precision.

Comment: @rasher +1 , link very useful

Comment: @rasher : I found that `Array[{#, f[#]} &, n]][[1]` is a litte bit slower than `Table[{b, f[b]}, {b, 1, n}]`, which is `124.426 vs 105.565` when `n = 25`.

Comment: @user565739: check update re: creation.

Comment: @rasher I think it is always useful to see get multiple answers and this has been a useful comparative exercise done by you and OP.  I only provided point estimate...anyway back to the salt mines for me...

Comment: @rasher:  For n=2^26=67100084, 140.8 vs 59.2, impressive!!

Answer (score 2):

Just exploiting another feature of `SparseArray` and for sample of size $10^6$.

Setting up:

```
fun[n_] := Table[{i, Mod[PowerMod[i, n, n] - i, n]}, {i, 1, n}];
data = fun[1000000];
```

Using `"NonzeroPositions"`:

```
nozero= SparseArray[Last@Transpose@data]["NonzeroPositions"]; // Timing
zero = Complement[List /@ Range[Length@data], ans]; // Timing
```

yielded:{0.078125, Null}, {0.093750, Null} respectively.

Example:

```
zero
Extract[data, zero]
```

yields:

```
{{1}, {109376}, {890625}, {1000000}}
{{1, 0}, {109376, 0}, {890625, 0}, {1000000, 0}}
```

Comment: +1 - I feel like a dufus forgetting that property, that I use in the answer I linked... DOH!

Comment: @rasher sadly but productively DOH moments are how I learn